# custom kml icons

Tags: kml

I'm trying to create a custom icon to display on google earth. It resides on my local filesystem, and I'm trying to reference it as "file:/C:/myfile.png" but it does not display. Is this possible to do?

Comment: For local URI references on windows usually need 3 slashes e.g. file:///C:/kml/icons/myicon.png or simply a relative path location from the KML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to package the KML and the icons together into a KMZ archive (which is just a zip).

[See my answer in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265808/java-api-for-kml-jak-embedding-images-in-kmz-files/7277791#7277791) .

Answer (score 1):

The [KML documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#icon) says that it works with any URI, local or web based. I suggest you don't use "file:/c:/myfile.png" but rather just the filepath "c:\myfile.png" or perhaps put the icon in the local directory and just use "myfile.png" as the example in the documentation suggests (also, you might need to make sure the backslashes are Windows based on a windows machine.)